# What is the tax rate/amount that I can deduct as an F1 Spanish national (tax treaty) on OPT living in the US?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I'm a post-completion F1 OPT student working in a company. I think I'm eligible to applying the tax treaty as described in Article 22.1 of the [tax treaty](http://photos.state.gov/libraries/spain/164311/tratados_bilaterales_2013/Taxation_TIAS_1591.pdf), but I don't know how much I can deduct. I've been told $1050 per year, but I can't find this number in any official document. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

$5000. It says it right there.

> income from personal services performed in that other Contracting State in an aggregate amount not in excess of 5,000 United States dollars or its equivalent in Spanish pesetas for any taxable year.

Although since it mentions pesetos, it might be slightly outdated.

Comment: Maybe it's the wording that confuses me. It says "An individual [...] shall be exempt from tax with respect to [...] income in an aggregate amount not in excess of $5,000 [...] for any taxable year". Does that mean I can deduct up to $5000 from my income tax? or that only the first $5,000 of my income is tax free?

Comment: Isn't it the same thing?